# RemoteAction's Exception message

Tags: exception, remote-action

Currently, Whenever an exception is encountered in RemoteAction, the response looks like something below

```
[{
"statusCode":200,
"type":"rpc",
"tid":5,
"ref":false,
"action":"vchav1.DeepViewController",
"method":"saveNotes",
"result":"Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, The message in the rule: []"
}]
```

could this be further refined to contain multiple details like:

```
"result":
[{"exception":"FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION", 
"message":"The message in the rule"}]
```

Or, how to extract the exact error message "The message in the rule"?

Comment: "The message in the rule" is text that has been written into your validation rule's error message text field. That text is not generated by Salesforce. Are you just asking how to get that value given either one of the two structures that might be contained in the `result:` member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Apex, Javascript will allow you to use "try-catch" blocks to capture different kinds of errors/exceptions and also "throw" custom exception or error "messages" when you've captured one. This [tutorial at w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp) will explain and walk you through examples of how to use these features of javascript.

Comment: yes...thats a good approach..I was wondering if this could be internal feature from Salesforce...as the message is not at all user-friendly...So, we would need to write the same messages again in custom labels or hardcoded...

Comment: Idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrjAAAS